# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: axios is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, axios

When I try to load my html page i get this error:

**Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: axios is not defined
at get (index.js:7)**

When I import it as `import axios from 'axios';` i get:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

So either way it's not working properly. I have used `npm install axios` too and mentioned the source in the html file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.23.0/axios.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

I just don't notice what I could have done wrong. Here's the script sample as it follows:

```
     const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';
    
    async function get(url) {
      return (await axios(url)).data;
    }
    
    async function loadTable() {
      let data = await get(apiUrl + 'getList');
      let tableDiv = document.getElementById('tableData');
   // and so on
```

I got the api running OK, the only problem is this axio reference.
The node script is running fine in another .js file, also Postman can identify it with no problem. Same port, same URL.

Comment: Have you imported Axios inside a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a HTML page, like one you would open in your browser, `npm` won't be able to add Axios into the page for you. You can consider Node.js code as server-side and your browser as client-side (note this isn't always the case, but it is here).

Also note, `import` is meant for Node.js code, and will not work in HTML code without an additional framework, which I assume you are not using here.

Your `script` tags are correctly, but they are probably not bring added to your HTML file at the right point. You can use either of these configurations, and it should work:

Script is importing **before** the elements of the page are created:

```html
<head>
    ...
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="yourCustomCode"></script>
<body>
```

Script is importing **after** the elements of the page are created:

```html
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="yourCustomCode"></script>
<body>
```

Either way, just **ensure the Axios package is higher up then the code you want to run with Axios**.

Comment: yep, and i have the node in another script.js as i mentioned, the api is running fine, Postman can identify it with no problem. same port, same link.

Comment: Omg right, i did not put the Axios package above the code. Thanks a lot! I've been struggling for the past 2 hours.

Comment: @thhhhhhhh Glad you figured it out. Definitely been there before myself!